# Create a ID value based on an incremental value when a value in a column changes in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create a 'segment' ID so that:

1. If the value (in one column) is the same as the row before you maintain the same segment ID
2. However, if the value (in one column) is different than the row before the segment ID increments by one

I am currently trying to achieve this via:

```
require(dplyr)
person <- c("Mark","Mark","Mark","Mark","Mark","Steve","Steve","Tim", "Tim", "Tim","Mark")
df <- data.frame(person,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$segment = 1

df$segment <- ifelse(df$person == dplyr::lag(df$person),dplyr::lag(df$segment),dplyr::lag(df$segment)+1)
```

But I am not getting the desired result through this method.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: So what's the desired output? Does the last Mark get the same value as the first Marks?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to increment on change, try this

```
df %>% mutate(segment = cumsum(person != lag(person, default="")))
#    person segment
# 1    Mark       1
# 2    Mark       1
# 3    Mark       1
# 4    Mark       1
# 5    Mark       1
# 6   Steve       2
# 7   Steve       2
# 8     Tim       3
# 9     Tim       3
# 10    Tim       3
# 11   Mark       4
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution might look like this

```
c(1, cumsum(person[-1] != person[-length(person)]) +1)
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4
```