# ggplot add segments to scatter plot according to factors

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter, segment

I have the following 'code'

```
set.seed(100)
values<-c(rnorm(200,10,1),rnorm(200,2.1,1),rnorm(250,6,1),rnorm(75,2.1,1),rnorm(50,9,1),rnorm(210,2.05,1))
rep1<-rep(3,200)
rep2<-rep(0,200)
rep3<-rep(1,250)
rep4<-rep(0,75)
rep5<-rep(2,50)
rep6<- rep(0,210)
group<-c(rep1,rep2,rep3,rep4,rep5,rep6)
df<-data.frame(values,group)
```

I would like to plot these data as a scatter plot (like the attached plot) and add segments. These segments (y values) shall represent the mean value of the data for a given group. In addition, the segments should have a different color depending on the factor (group). Is there an efficient way to do it with ggplot ?
Many thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this by augmenting your data a little. We'll use `dplyr` to get the mean by `group`, and we'll create variables that give the observation index and one that increments by one each time the `group` changes (which will be helpful to get the segments you want):<sup>1</sup>

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
    mutate(idx = seq_along(values), group = as.integer(group)) %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(m = mean(values)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(group2 = cumsum(group != lag(group, default = -1)))
```

Now we can make the plot; using `geom_line()` with grouping by `group2`, which changes every time the group changes, makes the segments you want. Then we just color by (a discretized version of) `group`:

```
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = idx, y = values)) +
    geom_point(shape = 1, color = "blue") +
    geom_line(aes(x = idx, y = m, group = group2, color = as.factor(group)),
              size = 2) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "black", "green", "blue"),
                       name = "group") +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup> See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42705593/8386140